# django invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','

Tags: django

I want to pass a url like this:

```
/view/people/?roles=1,2
```

where 1,2 is formed from a javascript function. In my view I have this:

```
roles=request.GET.get('roles',None)
if roles:
    roles=list(roles)
    if type(roles) is list:
        filter_options['role__in']=roles
```

and i get the above error. If I hard code roles as:

```
   filter_options['role__in']=[1,2,3]
```

Comment: what? if you hardcode you dont get error?

Comment: Have a look at the value `roles` holds after you do `roles=list(roles)`. I think you'll be surprised. (It's not `[1,2]`.)

Comment: @Exprator no. I get correct results.

Comment: @Chris you are onto something, arent you? Lemme look.

Comment: thanks Chris...in fact it was '1',',','2'. Very helpful insight (and true, surprising)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `request.GET.get('roles', None)` returns the string `'1,2'`. Since strings are iterable you won't get an error when you iterate over them (e.g. `for foo in '1,2'`) or generate a list from them using `list()`. But in both cases the iteration is over the *characters in the string*.

If you are careful to accept only comma-separated integers (e.g. in your URL pattern) you can deal with this manually by `split()`ing the string on `','` and converting each element to an integer, e.g.

```
roles = request.GET.get('roles', None)
if roles:
    roles = [int(role) for role in roles.split(',')]
    filter_options['role__in'] = roles
```

Note that we are assuming that `int(role)` will work here, which is why the URL pattern is so important.